# flash UI, how to drag symbol with tween

Tags: flash, adobe

I want to drag symbol that has a tween. As soon as I drag, tween gets messed up, since flash thinks I want to manually adjust tween. No, I just changed size of stage and want to tween start and end same way but in different position. You could drag by tween line, but this particular tween just changes opacity so no luck. Is there some shift-control-something key sequence to drag symbol with tween intact?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean:

you have a symbol on a timeline and this symbol has at least two instances on the timeline, connected by a timline tween.

then you cannot move either end or any part of that tween independently without affecting the tween.  A timeline tween gets its parameters (ie starting x, starting alpha etc) from the movieclip's properties.  If you move a movieclip instance that is the start of your tween, you are changing that movieclip's parameters (ie, x, y etc), thus affecting the outcome of your tween.

To move around a movieclip tweened on a timeline across multiple instances, you need to turn on **edit Multiple frames**, and **onion all** from the selections at the bottom of the timeline panel (down by the horizontal scrollbar).

**EDIT**

In regards to your comment, my suggestion is indeed your solution, and attached is a screenshot of the "onion all"!

(click link to see screen shot, i can;t seem to put it right in this message)

[alt text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmOE5.jpg)

Comment: there is no onion all in cs5. and I dont think this last paragraph is answer I am looking for. Is there a way to drag and drop tweened movie clip without changing tween?